# Does a closed subset $E$ of $X\times X$ induce a closed quotient map $X\rightarrow X/E$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space. Let $E$ be an equivalence relation on $X$. If $E$ is closed in $X\times X$ with the product topology, is the canonical map $p:X\rightarrow X/E$ closed?

If in addition $X$ is compact and Hausdorff, then $p$ is closed. I'm not able to see if this is true in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is false in general. Let $R$ be the equivalence relation on the $X = \mathbb{R}$ defined by $xRy$ iff $x=y$ or $x \neq 0 \land y = \frac{1}{x}$.

This relation is closed in $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$, but the quotient map is not closed, as witnessed by the fact that the saturation of $[1,\infty)$ is the non-closed set $(0,\infty)$ (so the image of $[1,\infty)$ under $p$ is not closed, as the inverse image of that image (the saturation) is not closed).

The reverse also fails (for any non-Hausdorff space $X$): the identity relation on such a space has a closed quotient map (it's a homeomorphism...) but the relation as a subset of the square is the diagonal which is closed iff $X$ is Hausdorff.